# How to implement reusable angular component that contain 1-N other components dynamically?

Tags: angular

How this is done so that the container component does not have any knowledge about the components it contains?

I'm trying to develope a general side-panel control that can contain anything. Each component is represented by an icon in the selector row on the top and below are vertically placed components. Clicking the icon scrolls the container so that corresponding component become visible.

Static example where the different items are just in same html is here:

```
  <mat-sidenav opened mode="side" position="end">
   <div class="sidewindow">
    <div class="header">
      <button  mat-icon-button (click)="scroll(properties)">
          <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button  mat-icon-button (click)="scroll(table)">
          <mat-icon>table_chart</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button  mat-icon-button (click)="scroll(maintenance)">
          <mat-icon>gavel</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div #properties>
        <mat-card >
            <mat-card-title>Properties</mat-card-title>
              <form class="example-form">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
                </mat-form-field>
              </form>
            </mat-card>
      </div>
      <div  #table>
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-title>Table</mat-card-title>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <!-- Position Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Weight Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Symbol Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
      <div #maintenance>
          <mat-card>
              <mat-card-title>Maintenance</mat-card-title>
              <mat-card-subtitle>Subtitle</mat-card-subtitle>
              <p>The actual content</p>
              <p>The actual content 2</p>
              <p>The actual content 3</p>

          </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways based on your need:

1. Using `ng-content` you can project the child components in your side-panel component. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/
2. You can use `NgComponentOutlet` to dynamically attach components into your side-panel template with control to inject custom data as well. https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet#description
3. Using `ComponentFactoryResolver` which can dynamically instantiate components.
   https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader

> Note: #2 and #3 require the components to be registered with the
>   `entryComponents` array for Angular to know about them at compile
>   time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is multislot transclusion with `ng-content`. You can check [Todd Motto's tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content) for example to see how to do this in Angular. You'll have to do adjustments in order to have your icon system, but this way you can include any component you want in your panel. Your html could look like:

```
<side-panel-component>
    <my-comp1></my-comp1>
    <my-comp2></my-comp2>
    <div class>...</div>
    ...
</side-panel-component>
```

I never did something like this but I used transclusion a lot, and I assume I would give it a try.